# HasItems Property in TreeViewItem true, even if all children are Visibility = Collapsed

Tags: c#, xaml

Can you please give me a hint, to make HasItems Property better.
I have a TreeView like this:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="{Binding AutomationId}" />
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FamilyName}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Code behind:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

        var homer = new Customer("Homer", "Simpson");
        homer.Customers.Add(new Customer("Bart", "Simpson"));
        homer.Customers.Add(new Customer("Lisa", "Simpson"));
        homer.Customers.Add(new Customer("Maggie", "Simpson"));
        var chief = new Customer("Chief", "Wiggum");
        chief.Customers.Add(new Customer("Ralf", "Wiggum"));
        Customers.Add(homer);
        Customers.Add(chief);

    }
```

The Class Customer implements INotifyPropertyChanged and everything is fine.
As you see here, I have a DataTrigger to change color depending on "HasItems" Property of the TreeViewItem.
The problem is: HasItems is true, even if all children are Hidden or Collapsed.

See here: I made the VISIBILITY of son of "Chief Wiggum" Collapsed. And "Chief Wiggum"-TreeViewItem is still red.

[image: With Ralfs TreeViewItem Collapsed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you could figure out, the fact the items are hidden doesn't mean the tree view has no items.

One possible approach is changing your DataTrigger in the following way:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items, Converter={StaticResource HasVisibleItemsConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
```

Create a **HasVisibleItemsConverter** converter class that implements `IValueConverter`, there you should check if there are any items that are visible - I'll leave that for your own exercise.

Then you create an instance of **HasVisibleItemsConverter** in the Resources area (either Window.Resources or UserControl.Resources):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:HasVisibleItemsConverter x:Key="HasVisibleItemsConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And don't forget to add `conv="..."` in the namespace definition for your Window/UserControl pointing to the assembly and namespace where your converter is.

Comment: This all doesn't work, because when I get HasItems from the Binding it is too late to convert. I can not convert bool to my itemstype. I solved it via a Binding to the DataContext. There I can look in a converter whether it has visible children or not.

Comment: Ouch, I was supposed to do the binding to Items, not HasItems. Sorry about the typo, I'm editing the answer. Glad you found a solution, though :)